# Symbols not found error when I appear to be including proper header

Tags: c++, c, header-files, bison, flex-lexer

I hope this hasn't been answered, it's hard to read through similar questions because they all seem to be about iOS development in Xcode. I'm writing a parser and need a header included in both my grammar (.y) and my lexer (.l) files. Originally just including the header and not defining the functions gave a duplicate symbol error. I read up a bit on C++ and tried to make a header file and a cpp file. Now I'm getting a `symbol(s) not found error`. I think I just need some help from someone who knows C++ better than me. Also I'm slowly converting this code from C to C++ so there are some non-C++ ways of doing things right now.

The exact error is :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "symlook(char*)", referenced from:
      yylex() in lex.yy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [outfile] Error 1
```

## symtab.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NSYMS 20

struct symtab
{
    char *name;
    // ptr to C function to call if this entry is a fucntion name
    double (*funcptr)();
    double value;
};

extern symtab table[];

struct symtab *symlook(char *s);
void addfunc(char *name, double (*func)());
```

## symtab.cpp

```
#include "symtab.h"

symtab table[NSYMS];

struct symtab *symlook(char *s) {
    char *p;
    struct symtab *sp;

    for(sp = table; sp < &table[NSYMS]; sp++) {
        /* is it already here? */
        if(sp->name && !strcmp(sp->name, s))
            return sp;
        if(!sp->name) { /* is it free */
            sp->name = strdup(s);
            return sp; 
        }
        /* otherwise continue to next */
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Too many symbols");
    exit(1);    /* cannot continue */
} /* symlook */

void addfunc(char *name, double (*func)())
{
    struct symtab *sp = symlook(name);
    sp->funcptr = func;
}
```

## simple.l

```
%{
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "symtab.h"
%}

%%

"if"    return IF;

"true"  return TRUE;
"false" return FALSE;

([0-9]+|([0-9]*\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?) {
        yylval.dval = atof(yytext); 
        return NUMBER; 
}

[ \t] ;  /* ignore whitespace */
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*   { 
        yylval.symp = symlook(yytext);
        return NAME; 
}

"$"     return 0; /* logical EOF */

\n      |
.       return yytext[0];
%%
```

## simple.y

```
%{
    #include "symtab.h"
    #include "ast.h"
    #include <string>
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);
%}

%union {
    double dval;
    int ival;
    struct symtab *symp;
}

%token <symp> NAME
%token <ival> INTEGER_LITERAL
%token <dval> NUMBER
%token IF TRUE FALSE WHILE
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%nonassoc UMINUS

%type <dval> num_expression
%%

statement_list: statement '\n'
    |   statement_list statement '\n'
    ;

statement:  NAME '=' num_expression  { $1->value = $3; }
    |       num_expression           { fprintf(stderr, "= %g\n", $1); }
    |       if_expression
    |       bool_expression
    |       while_expression
    ;

num_expression: num_expression '+' num_expression   { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    |       num_expression '-' num_expression       { $$ = $1 - $3; }
    |       num_expression '*' num_expression       { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    |       num_expression '/' num_expression   
                { 
                    if($3 == 0.0)
                        yyerror("divide by zero");
                    else
                        $$ = $1 / $3;
                }
    |       '-' num_expression %prec UMINUS { $$ = -$2; }
    |       '(' num_expression ')'          { $$ = $2; }
    |       NUMBER                      
    |       NAME                            { $$ = $1->value; }
    |       NAME '(' num_expression ')'     { } //$$ = ($1->funcptr($3)); }
    ;
bool_expression: FALSE
    |            TRUE
    ;

if_expression:   IF '('  bool_expression ')' '{' statement '}'
    |            IF '(' ')' '{' '}'
    ;

while_expression: WHILE '('  bool_expression ')' '{' statement '}'
    |             WHILE '(' ')' '{' '}'
    ;

%% 

void yyerror(char *str)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error %s", str);
}


int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

## makefile

```
CC=g++
outfile=simple
lexfile=simple
yaccfile=simple

outfile: compile
    ${CC} -o ${outfile}.out lex.yy.o y.tab.o -ll

compile: build
    ${CC} -c symtab.cpp
    ${CC} -c lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll


build:
    yacc -d ${yaccfile}.y
    flex ${lexfile}.l
```

Comment: Un*defined* != un*declared*.

Comment: when compiling, any parameters about libraries `-ll` are ignored (and should not be there at all)

Comment: when writing the compile steps (those calls to $(CC) with the parameter `-c` if you had included the `-o outputname` parameter, then it would have been obvious as to the root of the problem.  In general, it is best to only try to compile a single file when calling $(CC) with the `-c` parameter.  The `build`, compile` targets do not produce a file of the same name, so early in the makefile, needs to be the statement: `.PHONY: build compile`

Comment: when defining macros, (usually) the macro is to only be evaluated once.  The `=` results in the macro being re-evaluated each time it is referenced.  Much better to use `:=` so the macro is only evaluated once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `compile: build` step produces a file `symtab.o` that you are not including on the link line.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I knew it'd be something simple but all of the documentation I found was very lengthy or cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common mistake. The problem lies here:

```
#include "y.tab.h"
#include <math.h>
#include "symtab.h"
```

1. In your Makefile you need to do first `yacc's` command because `yacc` is generating your `"y.tab.h"` file.
2. You need to `#include "y.tab.h"`after all other includes! Think about this! `y.tab.h` will have something from `"symtab.h"` but Lex doesn't know what that is since you've included `"symtab.h"` after `"y.tab.h"`.

**So remember:** *You always have to include* `"y.tab.h"` after all other includes to avoid this error!

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the compilation to fail, as opposed to the linking step?